# Pandas: load csv file as a list

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

```
customer  gender customer_ids
  1         0       [1,2,3]
  2         1       [6,2,1]
  3         0       [4,3,9]
```

I have some data in a csv file as above. I load the csv file like this

```
df = pd.read_csv('customer.csv', sep='\t')
```

This loads the customer_ids as string like this `"['1','2','3']", ...`

But I need the customer_ids data as numpy array like this

```
[list([1,2,3]), list([6,2,1]), list([4,3,9])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While loading in your data, specify a `converters` parameter -

```
df = pd.read_csv('customer.csv', sep='\t', converters={'customer_ids' : pd.eval})
df

   customer  gender customer_ids
0         1       0    [1, 2, 3]
1         2       1    [6, 2, 1]
2         3       0    [4, 3, 9]

df.customer_ids.tolist()
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 2, 1], [4, 3, 9]]
```

Comment: instead of df.customer_ids.tolist(), this is working df.customer_ids.values